# Is it possible to get a distinct list of keys in an embedded map in a mongodb collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-query

Imagine I have a Java object with the following fields:

```
public class MyObject {
    public String foo;
    public Map<String, String> baz;
}
```

If I save some of these objects into mongodb, it looks like this:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": {
        "key1": "value1"  
        "key3": "value2" 
    }
},
{
    "foo": "bar2",
    "baz": {
        "key2": "value3",
        "key3": "value4"
    }
}
```

The keys in the `baz` map are of interest to me but I only want to get hold of a **distinct** list of the keys each document contains. The nature of the map is that it can *possibly* contain a finite number of known keys; I'd like to know which of these known keys are currently being used throughout the documents in my collection. I don't care about the values against these keys, so, the output I'd want is:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
```

Is there a query I can run to get this kind of return data?

Comment: There is certainly an answer that has been here for a long time suggesting a mapReduce approach in  order to inspect the documents. However I suspect your real use case would be better suited to changing "baz" to an array like: `{ "baz": [{ "key": "key1", "value": "value1"},{ "key": "key3", "value": "value2" }] }` where simple calls to `.aggregate()` or `.distinct()` will get the list from "baz.key" without JavaScript traversal. And also likely suits your end use case ( not really mentioned in an abstract question ) better as well.

Comment: You're right; using an array of objects would be better, however I'm unfortunately not in a position to change the structure of this object. I appreciate it's a bit of a weird use-case but that's all I've got to work with at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback on the format of my question. However, I do feel like I'm being misrepresented here. I know exactly what it is I want out of this problem; I want a distinct list of keys based on the data I have provided in the question above. The _why_ of it is quite irrelevant. You have to appreciate that this is the result of me being given an object and being told I need that list of keys. That is an inherent problem of engineering in big business; I don't have the ability to change this design as it's not in my control.